# PHP code convert to PHP/MySQLi OOP

Tags: php, mysqli

today i tried to convert my code to PHP/MySQLi OOP code.

```
class Database
{
private $host;
private $user;
private $password;
private $db;
private $mysqli;

function __construct()
{
    $this->host = "*****";
    $this->user = "*****";
    $this->password = "******";
    $this->db = "*****";

    $this->mysqli = new mysqli($this->host, $this->user, $this->password, $this->db);

    if (mysqli_connect_errno()):
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    endif;
}
}
```

This is a script for the query's:

```
include_once("WD_Config/database.php");

class Adressen_Db
{
function __construct()
{
    $this->database = new Database();
}

public function selecteer()
{
    $query = "SELECT * FROM wd_adressen WHERE verborgen = 0 ORDER BY naam ASC";
    $result = $this->database->mysqli->query($query);

    return $result;
}
}
```

And this is how i call it.

```
$adressen = new Adressen_Db;
$adressen_result = $adressen->selecteer();

echo "<p>";
while ($row = $adressen_result->fetch_assoc()):
echo "<a href='http://maps.google.com/?q=".$row['voladres']."'     target='_blank'>".$row['naam']."</a> woonachtig op <i>".$row['voladres']."</i><br>";
endwhile;
echo "</p>";
```

I alway get a "Call to a member function query() on a non-object". Doesn't matter what i trie ...

Can somebody tell me why that is?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to change private to public. `private $mysqli;` to `public $mysqli;`.

Comment: `Database::mysqli` is private

Comment: Thanks Dave, that did work! But shouldn't $mysqli always be private?

Comment: @PeeHaa Isn't `::` for static variables?

Comment: @DaveChen [Nope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php) :)

Comment: @MarkieMark You can make a getter method, such as `public getMysql() { return $this->mysqli; }`. But it must be public (or accessible via a getter method) because you're trying to access it within another class, `Adressen_Db`. So if the class isn't extended from it, (i.e protected would work then), then you must make it public. In all cases, a getter method would work. **tl;dr**: extends -> protected, not extended -> public, anything -> getter method.

Comment: @PeeHaa I mean, could you refer private variables (well I know you can't refer to them in code anyways) in that way? I thought `::` only worked on static or constants.

Comment: The `::` in my comment is just to denote the specific variable in the class. Look for example at the docs of the [`DateTime`](http://nl1.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) class. Those methods are not static.

Comment: shouldn't it be `$adressen = new Adressen_Db();` ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think while you definitely need to have `$mysqli` as public so it can be accessed in the other method, there might be something else, as the error would be something like

> trying to access private property in database class

or something like that, whereas your script throws a non-object call error

I think your `new Adressen_Db;` lacks the parenthesis:

```
$adressen = new Adressen_Db();
```

Answer (score 5):

The `$mysqli` variable in class Database is declared `private`.

You can access it only through setters and getters.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace your code with this:
Config.php

```
<?php

define("DB_HOST", "localhost");
define("DB_USER", "root");
define("DB_PASS", "");
define("DB_NAME", "your_database_name");
```

**Now include this file in your database file**

```
require_once 'config.php';

Class Database {

    public $host = DB_HOST;
    public $user = DB_USER;
    public $pass = DB_PASS;
    public $dbname = DB_NAME;
    public $link;
    public $error;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->getConnection();
    }

    private function getConnection() {
        $this->link = new mysqli($this->host, $this->user, $this->pass, $this->dbname);
        if (!$this->link) {
            $this->error = "Connection failed" . $this->link->connect_error;
            return false;
        }
    }

    // for only select query
    public function select($query) {
        $result = $this->link->query($query) or
                die($this->link->error . __LINE__);
        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            return $result;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    // for insert, delete and update
    public function myquery($query) {
        $myquery = $this->link->query($query) or
                die($this->link->error . __LINE__);
        if ($myquery) {
            return $myquery;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

**Now, make your queries like this:**

```
<?php
require_once './lib/Database.php';
?>

<?php

class Admin {

    private $db;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->db = new Database();
    }

    public function getData(){
        $query = "SELECT * FROM admin";
        $result = $this->db->select($query);
        if($result != false){
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
                // do your thing
            }
        }
    }

    public function insert(){
        $query = "INSERT INTO admin(admin_name) VALUES('$admin_name')";
        $result = $this->db->myquery($query);
        if($result){
            $msg = "User has been added successfully.";
            return $msg;
        } else {
            $msg = "Error while adding user. Please try again.";
            return $msg;
        }
    }

}
```

Do this.